# Radial gradient showing as all-white

Tags: css, air, webkit

According to [an Adobe forum thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/915475), radial gradients are supported as of AIR 3.0, but both of the following lines of CSS inside `body{}` just show as all-white:

```css
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #088fe0), color-stop(50%, #001193), color-stop(100%, #00025f));
```

```css
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #088fe0 0%, #001193 50%, #00025f 100%);
```

I *am* able to use a linear gradient successfully:

```css
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #088fe0), color-stop(100%, #00025f));
```

What's going wrong here?

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64, with AIR v3.6.0.6090 when using `adl`, and v3.8.0.1430 when running the compiled version.

Comment: I tried the top 2.. The first doesn't work, however, the second does.

Comment: Yes, I tried them in Adobe AIR.

Comment: @JoshC How odd! Are you running the same version as me? `air.trace(air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion);`

Comment: @JoshC I'm still unable to get the gradient to display after upgrading to 3.8

Comment: @JoshC Still trying to solve this. I initially thought it was because my application descriptor was using namespace 2.0 (`<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0">`) but changing this to `3.6` doesn't help. I've also created a blank application, and am still seeing the same behaviour. Do you have any ideas of how to debug further?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/xFPuY/) for better understanding, Please see the details,

only the first one is not working in Chrome browser..

other two are working fine.

please provide more details for your problem with browser specification.

Edit: Update on basis of requirements

I have updated [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/xFPuY/1/) that is working fine now,

The first gradient filter was not working because you have to keep in mind it does not work with % size and

also you must not specify size in PX it is implied; If you specify in px that makes if not working.

I have update this works fine in Chrome(-webkit browser.) should work with AIR too.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 100, color-stop(0%, #088fe0), color-stop(50%, #001193), color-stop(100%, #00025f));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but it's for Adobe AIR, which runs Webkit.

Comment: Chrome is also one of Webkit browser. for Adobe AIR there are alternate ways please refer this link to Book page  http://books.google.co.in/books?id=sMHekSGEl6MC&lpg=PT87&ots=U4x2WieuwQ&dq=adobe%20air%20css%20-webkit%20gradient%20help&pg=PT87#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: +1 for this and I agree to @MarmiK because Chrome, Safari, and the latest 2 versions of Opera are now running Webkit you can test webkit on them too!

Answer (score -1):

Set the fallback color and use background-image to see if the version of webkit doesn't support the gradient:

```
body {
  background: red; /* fallback */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, #088fe0), color-stop(50%, #001193), color-stop(100%, #00025f));
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #088fe0 0, #001193 50%, #00025f 100%);
}
```

Comment: This should not work, if you see the red color the webkit version in your adobe air version doesn't support the gradients, if you do not see the red color the bug is somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

As noted already, only the first one doesn't work in the latest Chrome (that was for older versions).

For maximum compatibility across browsers though, you'll probably want to include a few declarations here

Old browsers that don't support gradients, default to a flat colour:

```
background: #088fe0;
```

Firefox:

```
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #088fe0 0%, #001193 50%, #00025f 100%);
```

Older Chrome & Safari versions (both using the WebKit engine):

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#088fe0), color-stop(50%,#001193), color-stop(100%,#00025f));
```

Newer Chrome & Safari versions (and probably Opera 15+):

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #088fe0 0%,#001193 50%,#00025f 100%);
```

Older (pre-webkit) Opera:

```
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #088fe0 0%,#001193 50%,#00025f 100%);
```

IE 10:

```
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #088fe0 0%,#001193 50%,#00025f 100%);
```

Older IE (just linear gradients available in the directx filter, I think):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#088fe0', endColorstr='#00025f',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

And what browsers should be using (the standards version):

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #088fe0 0%,#001193 50%,#00025f 100%);
```

If you put all these options in, you should get the gradients anywhere they're suported.

Comment: I think you also missed that this isn't for a browser, it's for Adobe AIR.